# Hibernate gradle plugin: HibernateEnhance task cannot resolve compileOnly dependecies

Tags: hibernate, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I tried to update the existing hibernate Gradle plugin from `5.6.9.Final` to `6.1.0.Final` like this:

**Old configuration:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.6.9.Final'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

hibernate {
    enhance {
        enableLazyInitialization = true
        enableDirtyTracking = true
    }
}
```

**New configuration:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.hibernate.orm' version '6.1.0.Final'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

hibernate {
    enhancement {
        lazyInitialization = true
        dirtyTracking = true
    }
}
```

The new version, also added 3 Gradle tasks:

- compileJpaMetamodel
- generateJpaMetamodel
- hibernateEnhance

The last task fails, if I use some compileOnly dependecies like:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
}
```

I tried to use `implementation` instead of `compileOnly`, but this didn't help.

How can I make it work?

This is the reproducer: https://github.com/stefan-dan/hibernate_enhance_plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue from the [**Hibernate**](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15353).

They have fixed it in version `6.1.5.Final`.